# hibernate delete doesn't work

Tags: hibernate, session, transactions

I'm experiencing a weird situation, where hibernate delete works on all records but not on id=`1`. At first, I was using `getCurrentSession` to retrieve active hibernate session, but changed it to manually open/close new session for delete, since it was not working. But now it still doesn't work. Even though, I'm using transactions.

```
@Override
public void delete(Song song) {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {
      Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
      session.delete(song);
      tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
      System.out.println("notify!");
    }
    session.close();
}
```

I've got 5 test records. I can delete id={2,3,4,5}, but I cannot delete id=1. Any ideas?

edit: [this](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/lyricsBase/blob/master/src/main/java/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/lyricsbase/model/Song.java) is the code of my Song entity.

Comment: Does your `Song` entity have some relationship ? with cascading ?

Comment: @benzonico: my SOng entity's code is here: https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/lyricsBase/blob/master/src/main/java/com/blogspot/symfonyworld/lyricsbase/model/Song.java
No, I don't have any relationships.

Comment: One thing I notice is that you are setting the id to `1` by default. Event though i have no idea if it is really the root of your problem (but is sure smells like it).

Comment: Submit it as an answer so that I can accept it :) that was it... Anyway - do you know why could that be? What has the default id got to do with delete disabling?

Comment: Please post in the question the code of your entity for sake of history. I'll have a look at why it is a problem for deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice is that you are setting the id to `1` by default. Even though i have no idea if it is really the root of your problem (but is sure smells like it).